# Deseo eliminar borde (frontera en blanco) entre boton en material design

Tags: java, android, xml, botón, material-design

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola amigos, por favor, pueden ayudarme con esto, he estado averiguando y no
encuentro la forma correcta de eliminar ese espacio en blanco entre la imagen
y los botones. No existe ningun margen entre ellos.
Los botones de material por defecto tienen una "frontera blanca" tanto encima como debajo.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/a1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/material_text_button"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Me gusta"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2.5dp"
                    android:textSize="7sp"/>
                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_ingresar"
                    style="text_boton_cardview2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2.5dp"
                    android:text="Ingresar"
                    android:textSize="7sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
```

existe un método o style predeterminado para eliminar ese espacio en el TOP del button?
Gracias

Comment: Hola, el código en formato imagen no, debes copiar y pegar el código correctamente

Comment: ya lo hice, pero nadie aporta...

Comment: Estas seguro de que ese espacio no pertenece a la imagen?, si tienes un tamaño fijo definido para la imagen, intenta agregarle la propiedad `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` al `ImageView` en el xml. Si no funciona, entonces intenta agregarle `android:layout_margin="0dp"` a los botones. Puede ser que tenga alguna propiedad que debas sobreescribir. Para poder ayudarte,  te recomiendo que elimines la imagen del Xml y solo compartas el codigo del xml **completo** de tu layout, no basta con enfocarse solo en un componente, donde ni siquiera se puede ver como esta compuesto el `ImageView`.

Comment: con lo único que te puedo ayudar es con un voto a favor por que ni idea de eso. Pero me pasaba en `Swing` y eran los `JButton` que de forma predeterminada vienen con una separación de pixeles (5 si mal no recuerdo) que se puede deshabilitar, o setear. Seguramente ahí está el problema, los botones

Comment: de hecho fijate que la distancia que queres quitar es la misma que hay entre los botones. Averigua la forma de setear ese espacio, creo que era una propiedad del `layout`

Comment: Hola @Fabc_dev agrega el contenedor del LinearLayout, si es posible agrega todo el layout, el problema se encuentra afuera.

Comment: El tamaño pertenece a los botones. Les adjunto todo el code en breve